# Locating ASP Sitemap tree structures child nodes using Selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, sitemap

The website I am trying to automate can be navigated by using sitemap tree.Now in order to access the child nodes from selenium I wrote the following code:

```
IWebElement menu = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Setup"));
//Setup is the parent node
Actions mouseOver = new Actions(driver);
mouseOver.MoveToElement(menu).Build().Perform();
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Entities")).Click();
//Entities is the child node.
```

But webdriver throws an **Element not found** exception.

I am using Firefox for playing the test case.

Comment: Classic asp is not ASP.NET and C# was never an option with it. Please use the correct tags.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not waiting enough for element to appear and that's why 'element not found'. Did you try WebdriverWait?

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
IWebElement menu = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Setup"));
Actions mouseOver = new Actions(driver);
mouseOver.MoveToElement(menu).Build().Perform();
IWebElement entities = 
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.LinkText("Entities"))); 
entities.click();
```